# what to use instead of title widget in vs code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),title: Text("first")),
vs code editor said

```
"message": "'title' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use \"label\" instead, as it allows for an improved text-scaling experience. This feature was deprecated after v1.19.0..\nTry replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 25,
"startColumn": 68,
"endLineNumber": 25,
"endColumn": 73,
"tags": [
    2
]
```

}]

Comment: Use `label` instead of `title`.

Answer (score 0):

Use "label" widget instead of "title"

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      label: "Hello",
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'label' like
BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: Icon(Icons.home),
label: 'Home',
),